# JSP: How to get values by key in nested Map?

Tags: jsp

Assuming I have a following map, I want to print values in the nested map by key:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, someObject>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, someObject>>();
```

So, my approach was like the followings:

```
<c:forEach var="item1" items="${map}" varStatus="idx1">
   <c:forEach var="item2" items="${item1.value}" varStatus="idx2">
       <td>${item2['A'].variableInSomeObject}</td>
       <td>${item2['B'].variableInSomeObject}</td>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Also tried

```
<c:out value = "${item2['A'].variableInSomeObject}"/>
```

but it causes an error.
Please guide me what I am missing.

Comment: what do you mean by item2['A']. Do you want to get the object against a specific key 'A' in the inner map.

Comment: Yes, while iterating through the nested map, I want to print value by specific key.

Comment: Are you sure there is value in 'variableInSomeObject' of that particular object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `<c:forEach>` to iterate through the map, each item in iteration is an instance of `Map.Entry`. Each item have the `key` and the `value`. For item  `Map<Integer, Map<String, SomeObject>>` the `key` is the instance of `Integer` and the `value` is the instance of  `Map<String, SomeObject>`.

Assume that you have the following map and nested map:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, SomeObject>> outerMap = 
        new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, SomeObject>>();
Map<String, SomeObject> firstNestedMap = new HashMap<String, SomeObject>();
Map<String, SomeObject> secondNestedMap = new HashMap<String, SomeObject>();
```

And some object:

```
public class SomeObject {

    public Integer getVariableInSomeObject() {
        return variableInSomeObject;
    }

    public void setVariableInSomeObject(Integer variableInSomeObject) {
        this.variableInSomeObject = variableInSomeObject;
    }

    private Integer variableInSomeObject;
}
```

You can fill map's, for example, as shown below:

```
SomeObject firstSomeObject = new SomeObject();
firstSomeObject.setVariableInSomeObject(1);

SomeObject secondSomeObject = new SomeObject();
secondSomeObject.setVariableInSomeObject(2);

SomeObject thirdSomeObject = new SomeObject();
thirdSomeObject.setVariableInSomeObject(3);

SomeObject fourthSomeObject = new SomeObject();
fourthSomeObject.setVariableInSomeObject(4);

firstNestedMap.put("A", firstSomeObject);
firstNestedMap.put("B", secondSomeObject);

secondNestedMap.put("A", thirdSomeObject);
secondNestedMap.put("B", fourthSomeObject);

outerMap.put(1, firstNestedMap);
outerMap.put(2, secondNestedMap);
```

To iterate the nested map and get the values, use the following JSTL code:

```
<table>
<c:forEach var="item1" items="${map}">
    <c:forEach var="item2" items="${item1.value}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${item2.value.variableInSomeObject}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Accordingly, `item1.value` on each iteration will return instances of the nested map, i.e. `Map<String, SomeObject>`. `item2` will return instances of `SomeObject`. The expression `${item2.value.variableInSomeObject}` will return instances of the `Integer` fields.

As a result, you will get:

[image]